# How does ~ operator works in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operation

I was looking for some bit-Operations in Java and found the ~ operator.
I found following explenation:

> ~a results from a, by inverting all bits of a

So when I make a `System.out.println(~1)`, why is the output -2?
As 0001 = 1  after inverting it should be 1110

Comment: But 11 ... 1110 is -2. You may want to take a look how negative numbers work

Comment: You are right, because a negative number can be filled up with 1
I totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that negative numbers are stored in two's complement representation.  So that means you first take the complement of the number and then add 1.

```
int val = 20;
val = (~val)+1;
//  20     ==   0b00000000000000000000000000010100
// ~20     ==   0b11111111111111111111111111101011
// (~20)+1 ==   0b11111111111111111111111111101100 
System.out.println(val);
```

Prints

```
-20
```

And whether the value is an integer or floating point, the high order bit is the sign bit.  `1` means negative, `0` means not negative.